# Parameterize Azure subscription in Vsts build task

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have some build tasks that should be ran against resources located in different Azure subscription. In order to have only one build definition to maintain, i need to be able to parameterize the Azure Subscription field.

For the moment, i have to duplicate the original build definition and only change the subscription in each one, that is painful ti maintain.

The sample below does not work. I tried with the subscription ID, the subscription name, connected service name...

[image: build task screenshot]

How can i do that ?

Comment: Have you tried to use the link settings button, top right corner of the task? This should make the setting a build variable you can change on queue

Comment: Good try, but the result is the same as trying to directly parameter the field. The task exits with `XXX-XXXX exists false credentials cannot be null ` wether i put in the subscription id or the connection name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t parameterize Azure subscription field in build or release.

There is a similar user voice that you can vote and follow up: [Allow service connections to be parameterized in task groups](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/17338603-allow-service-connections-to-be-parameterized-in-t)

Answer (score 3):

It's already supported by VSTS.

Here are the steps to follow:

1. Create a release definition with Azure resource group deployment tasks.
2. In all tasks, choose a valid endpoint. You’ll need to do it multiple times and a variable cannot be used here
3. Create a task group with the tasks above. It would not have Azure subscription as a parameter.
4. Go to the task group and for each task in the group, you can update the subscription to $(AzureSubscription)
5. On saving of the task group, the Azure subscription would be bubbled up a as a parameter

Comment: Not a viable solution when your build process relies on output variables (e.g. when using Azure ARM templates) since these don't work with Task Groups (see: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/245845/output-variables-defined-in-task-group-are-not-wor.html)